# Autowire Subclasses of Generic Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics, kotlin

In Spring Boot 2, using Kotlin, I am trying to create a series of components which all extend a generic class, but provide a specific type to it:

```
abstract class Super<in T: SomeType> {
  abstract fun someMethod(t: T): Boolean
}

// AnotherType and OneMoreType extend SomeType
@Component
class Sub1 : Super<AnotherType> {
  override fun someMethod(t: AnotherType) = true
}

@Component
class Sub2 : Super<OneMoreType> {
  override fun someMethod(t: OneMoreType) = true
}
```

This all compiles fine, but then I want to gather up all of these for another component:

```
@Component
class MyService(
  private val subs: List<Super<SomeType>>
)
```

This results in the `no beans` exception.

What am I missing to be able to get it to find these beans?

Comment: What provides the `List<Super<SomeType>>`? Or, is there a particular Spring Boot mechanism that you're expecting to provide it?

Comment: With normal beans, if you do a List of some component type, Spring will automatically get all beans of that type and put them in a list automatically. For example, if I have 3 beans of type `MyClass` (or subclasses of it), and I try to autowire `List<MyClass>`, it'll contain those 3 beans.

Comment: This is valid question. Curious in why someone downvoted this.

Comment: As am I. If I'm missing something obvious, please let me know.

Comment: @samanime, I didn't know that, thanks! (No downvote from me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I found was to accept a star-projected `Super<*>` and then cast it when I access it:

```
@Component
class MyService(
  private val subs: List<Super<*>>
) {
  @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
  fun getSub(): List<Super<SomeType>>? = subs[0] as List<Super<SomeType>>
}
```

This works, but I'm not in love with it because I have to do an unchecked cast. I also can't do a checked cast, because thanks to erasure, I can't determine the generic type (like with `is Super<SomeType>`).

Since `Super` has a bounds of `SomeType` it isn't particularly dangerous, just ugly.

Suggestions or a better solution would be appreciated.

Comment: i don't think there is a way to be more specific than `*`, but maybe you could make `Super` a `sealed` class, so that you can restrict the set of implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this case, the whole point is to be able to have lots of implementations of `Super<SomeType>` as I then do something with them all.